# Photoshop to unity

Tags: photoshop

Hello I made a spritesheet in photoshop. The process to make the spritesheet was fairly easy. The issue is when importing to Unity I get a white background and I don't know how to remove the white background from my spreadsheet in unity. I have taken the following steps to resolve this issue
First unchecked the background in photoshop.
Second I tried to remove background from each individual image in photoshop.
But no luck can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the asset and change its type to Sprites, instead of Default (in the Inspector); if you've already done that, how about trying .png files?

Comment: Thank you so much the change to

Comment: Thank you so much the change to .PNG format worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the updates to Unity of last year, they removed the option to use the image transparancy as alpha when using .psd files. The option was a checkbox in the import setting of the image, which is no longer shown.

You can however use an import preset with a preset that still has this option set.

What you can do is:

1. Create a preset when in the texture-importer panel. [How to make a preset?](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Presets.html)  [What is the texture-import panel?](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html)
2. Open the file which was created (e.g. myimporter.preset). You could use a file explorer in your project and search for the name
3. Then set these values to 1:

   `propertyPath: m_PSDRemoveMatte`

   `propertyPath: m_PSDShowRemoveMatteOption`
4. Apply this preset to all your psd files inside unity.

Now, importing a .psd file should work fine with transparancies.

Note: Unity's intent was for users to import .png files when dealing with transparancies. But I found it annoying to manually re-import all my .png files when i made changes to the .psd file.